# Transform a table of hex constants with sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a C++ source file with a large table of constants. They are s-boxes, and they look like [this](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/kalynatab.cpp):

```
const word64 T[8][256] =
{
    {
        0xa832a829d77f9aa8, 0x4352432297d41143, 0x5f3e5fc2df80615f, 0x061e063014121806,
        0x6bda6b7f670cb16b, 0x75bc758f2356c975, 0x6cc16c477519ad6c, 0x592059f2cb927959,
        0x71a871af3b4ad971, 0xdf84dfb6f8275bdf, 0x87a1874c35b22687, 0x95fb95dc59cc6e95,
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to wrap each 18 character constant in a C macro like so:

```
W64LIT(0xa832a829d77f9aa8), W64LIT(0x4352432297d41143), W64LIT(0x5f3e5fc2df80615f), W64LIT(0x061e063014121806)
```

I know sed is part of the solution, but I am having trouble with the "match a 16-digit hexadecimal part.

How do I wrap each 64-bit hexadecimal value in the `W64LIT` macro?

---

The reason for the massive change is an old Apple compiler found on PowerMacs. It produces a stream of:

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -pipe -c kalyna.cpp
kalyna.cpp:432: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
kalyna.cpp:509: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
kalyna.cpp:608: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
kalyna.cpp:713: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
...
```

However, we can't just add `ULL` because early Microsoft compilers can't handle that. So the macro keeps the peace between operating systems.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
sed 's/0x[0-9a-f]\{16\}/W64LIT(&)/g'
```

This wraps any sequence of 16 hex digits (lowercase only) prefixed with “0x”.

Comment: Man, that was perfect. Thank you very much. I'll be checking it in once testing completes.

Comment: Thanks again @Stephen. This answer just bailed me out again for Bernstein's [TweetNaCl](https://tweetnacl.cr.yp.to/software.html) library.